# How do I send a skype message to a group chat using google app script and Skype Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to send a message to a Skype group chat every time a google form is submitted using google app script. I have this code:

```
function test() {

    var url = "https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.35/SkypeBootstrap.min.js";
    var javascript = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    eval(javascript);

    var config = {
      apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
      apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
    }; 

    Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
      var Application = api.application;
    });

}
```

Everytime I run the function I get this error:

> ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

What I figured out is that client side code cannot be ran on google app scripts

Comment: You have a problem with including the Skype Bootstrap file, which is what are you trying to do in your code, not with sending a Skype message. Please edit your question.

Comment: I'm afraid this SDK works only on a web browser. Are you running your code on a browser or on server side like node.js?

Comment: The code is being run on a server by google

Comment: That's why it doesn't work. The window object is a browser thing and this Skype library need it to work properly.

Comment: Yes I know that, is it possible to remove all the client side code from the Skype library without breaking it?

Comment: It's copyrighted code, I don't think you have right. And the code is minified and obfuscated, good look understanding what it does.

Comment: You can run it client-side js (inside a iframe with several restrictions) by publishing your code as a web-app...  `window` will be defined. But you might run into other issues.